# SQL Query - Combine multiple rows to one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to write a SQL to combine data from multiple columns and rows into one row.

```
OrganizationId  Name    Type    Active
--------------------------------------
      1         Baker   County  Yes
      2         curry   county  Yes
```

Expected result:

```
SomeColumnName
-------------------------------
1BakerCountyYes2currycountyYes
```

Comment: what rdbms are you using?

Comment: anyway, your google query will look like this `<RDBMSNAME> group concat`

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL**

Use **[GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)**.

```
SELECT row_id,        
       group_concat( Value ORDER BY Value SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        @row_number:=1 AS row_id,
        CONCAT(OrganizationId ,Name,Type,Active) AS Value
    FROM
        Table1
     ORDER BY file_fields_id
     ) T
GROUP BY row_id;
```